# How to delete files but not directories via FTP (with TLS encryption) in Perl?

Tags: perl, ssl, encryption, ftp, robust

I am currently traversing directories of a bunch of servers using TLS encryption with Net::FTPSSL::Robust. I am wanting to download the files and then delete them as I download. I do NOT want to delete folder names.

Problem is, Robust only has a get() and it doesn't delete the files it takes. I know there has to be a way to do this. As you can see here, delete will not work since it's not part of Net::FTPSSL::Robust, though it IS part of Net::FTPSSL :

```
my $ftp = Net::FTPSSL::Robust->new
( Host    => $server->{'ip_address'}->{content}
, Port    => $port
, SECURITY_TLS => $encryption
, user  => $server->{'username'}->{content}
, password  => $server->{'password'}->{content}
, login_attempts => 3
);

$local_dir = $server->{'local_directory'}->{content} if($server->{'local_directory'}->{content});

# when needed, many attempts will be made to retrieve all
$ftp->get("/", "".$local_dir);
$ftp->delete("/")
```

Can anyone shine some light on this or have a better solution? I'm completely new to Perl, so thanks in advance.

Comment: Net::FTPSSL::Robust is a Net::FTP::Robust, which has the following [limitation](http://search.cpan.org/~markov/Net-FTP-Robust-0.08/lib/Net/FTP/Robust.pod#Limitations) with `get()`: *Files will not get deleted, not on the server and not on the client.* The focus of these modules seems to be on retrieving data, nothing more.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why not just use Net::FTPSSL or Net::SSLGlue::FTP instead of Net::FTPSSL::Robust ? Do you need anything special from Net::FTPSSL::Robust which the other modules do not offer?

Comment: Because of its power. And the fact that it downloads large files autonomously and the way it handles potential errors. Are you saying I can't work around using Robust?

Comment: Even if I use one of those other modules, how do I make sure I don't delete any folders?

Comment: Because deleting a file and deleting a directory are different FTP commands, e.g. you cannot delete a directory as long as you don't issue an rmdir command.

Comment: Can I use something like FTPSSL or FTP::Recursive over TLS?

Comment: Net::FTPSSL does TLS. Net::FTP does TLS too if you pimp it with Net::SSLGlue::FTP. I have no experience with Net::FTP::Recursive but from a short look at the code it just extends Net::FTP, so loading Net::SSLGlue::FTP should probably also make Net::FTP::Recursive be able to use TLS.